# Substrings in CMD Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am new to Win10 batch files and I am running into a problem. I want to parse a directory for files that meet a certain criteria and then return a substring of the file.

Example:

If the file name is 210526_FPRS.PAS.SKBTXNS.TXT -> I want to echo 210526_FPRS.PAS.SKBTXNS
If the file name is 210526_FPRS.PAS.XXXXXXX.TXT-> I want to take no action

Here is what I wrote:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "Looping through files..."
CD \blah
FOR %%G in ("*SKBTXNS*") DO ECHO %%G:~1,22%
```

**The output I am getting is:**  210526_FPRS.PAS.SKBTXNS.txt:~1,22

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot substring or do string replacement with the `FOR` meta-variable.  It must be assigned to an environmental variable first with the `SET` command.

Comment: To strip the extension, you can use `%%~nG`. You can't use wildcards in paths except for the very last element: `\*skbtxns\*` won't work. The `/R` switch could be helpful.

Comment: @Stephan, I'm almost sure that `\*` was meant to be `*`, but due to lack of code formatting of the initial post, such escaping was required for the `*` not to be interpreted as italic formatting style…

Comment: @aschipfl might be or not. Doesn't change the fact that a wildcard is not accepted at this position.

Comment: Also realize that substrings are an offset. Not the starting position.  So if you were using an environmental variable to do a substring and wanted the first 22 characters of the string it would be `%var:~0,22%`.

Comment: Thanks to all!  I was able to find a solution that got me the result that I was expecting.  I posted what I used above.

Comment: @user146372 if you solved your own question then you should create an answer below instead of putting it in your question.

Comment: @Squashman Sorry, I am still new to this forum only making a few posts thus far.  i will keep that in mind

Comment: @user146372 when you joined StackOverFlow you were prompted to take the [tour]. Most people just skip over it because they are in such a hurry to solve their problem.  But if they did read the [tour] and also read [ask] a good question, their problem usually gets resolved much quicker.

Comment: If I read your question, as you've submitted it, and without the code solution, _(you should not have posted there)_, the following does what your question asks, `If Exist "blah\210526_FPRS.PAS.SKBTXNS.TXT" Echo 210526_FPRS.PAS.SKBTXNS`. Your count does not make sense to me, because it looks as if what you intended to do was to just list the file basenames, i..e the file name without path or extension. If that was your intent then why not do it directly, `For %%G In ("blah\*.SKB*") Do Echo %%~nG`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF  
CLS  
ECHO Looping through files...  
CD \blah  
FOR %%G IN (\*SKB\*) DO (call :uFile: %%G)  
GOTO :eof  


:uFile  
SET _filename=%1  
SET _result=%_filename:~0,22%  
ECHO %_result%  

:eof
```

The issue that I found in my original code was that I was trying to update my variables inside the FOR loop.  What I needed to do was set them outside the loop via a subroutine.  From there I was able to adjust the substring value as needed for the situation.

Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.